# Makefile linking error: undefined main

Tags: c, gcc, makefile

```
target: $(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(wildcard ./src/*.c))
    @echo "making target"
    $(cc) $(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(wildcard ./src/*.c)) $(LIBS) -o gif 
#   $(cc) $(wildcard ./objects/*.o) $(LIBS) -o gif 

./objects/%.o: %.c
    @echo "making objects now"
    @mkdir -p ./objs
    $(cc) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) -c $< -o ./objects/$@
```

The problem is that the objects .o files are created in the src folder.
I want the objects to be created in the objects folder.Please help?

The output is

```
making target
gcc ./src/gif_display.o ./src/gif_lzw.o ./src/gif_read.o ./src/sysm.o ./src/x86_main.o -lm -lc -o gif
```

Comment: I think you need move you  clean down at put it at the end of file first

Comment: No, this doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Can you please post the output of "make target"?

Comment: [joshis1@(none) GIF_Utility]$ make target
echo "making target"
making target
gcc  -lm -lc -o gif 
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-redhat-linux/4.6.3/../../../crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x18): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [target] Error 1
[joshis1@(none) GIF_Utility]$

Answer (score 1):

Formatted another way, the output looks like this:

```
[joshis1@(none) GIF_Utility]$ make target
echo "making target"
making target
gcc -lm -lc -o gif
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-redhat-linux/4.6.3/../../../crt1.o: In function _start': (.text+0x18): undefined reference tomain' collect2: ld returned 1 exit status make: * [target] Error 1
[joshis1@(none) GIF_Utility]$
```

The actual compilation line is:

```
gcc -lm -lc -o gif
```

As you can see, there are no input files fed to the compiler, so the problem is in your usage of `patsubst`. If you replace it with something like this it will properly generate the list of files you want:

```
$(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(wildcard ./src/*))
```

Comment: Thank you!, I tried with it. Now it get the following problem. The .o are created in the source folder itself.

Comment: Please don't edit your question like that - if you have a different question then ask a new question, otherwise you make this answer look wrong because it doesn't relate to your original question

Answer (score 0):

You need to fix your patsubst to change the directory:

```
$(patsubst ./src/%.c,./objs/%.o,$(wildcard ./src/*.c))
```